# Unable to access the site after restoring the site collection backup in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, backup, restore

I have a site collection with several subsites, All page layouts are customized as farm solutions by using visual studio application pages, I tried to restore my site collection backup to another server, restoration successfully completed, but while accessing the subsite it throws an error message like these [image]

I checked log files it throws an error msg **failed to get the token from distributed cache**, I have no idea about this, Please Help us to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the wsp that deployed the page layouts installed in that farm? If not, install it.

Comment: @EricAlexander Site backup will already have the page layout right?

Comment: No Actually. The WSP are deployed to the farm and not the site collection (provided that you don't use sandboxed solutions). Check if the solutions are deployed to the Web Application in question. Also, you should be able to brows to http://SiteCollectionURL/_Layouts/settings.aspx to see the site and manage features...

Comment: Hi, I deployed the page layout after Restoration, 
Then It Replaced my Backup page layout so that I can't get the OOTB web parts from the  backup. any suggestion pls?@BennySkogberg